# Referencing the length of a HTML number form element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that takes numbers, and there is a **specific** (Phone number, or `phNo`) form element that I want to only accept 7 digits in length (no more, no less). Using Javascript the Idea is:

If element length not equal to 7: `true` else `false`

Here is my code:

```js
var phNo = document.getElementsByName('phNo'); //here I try to get
        the form value in the form of an object. This is where I think I am going wrong   

        var phNoString = phNo.toString(); //Not to sure if I need this line or not, read somewhere that .length only works on a string
        
        if(phNoString.length != 7) {
           //Do something for false 
           return;
        } else {
          //Do something for true
        }
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">   
            First name: <input type="text" name="fName"><br>
            Last name: <input type="text" name="lName"><br>
            Phone Number: <input type="number" name="phNo" max="7"><br>
            Credit Card Number: <input type="number" name="cardNo"><br>
          </form>
          <input id="submit" type="button"value="Submit"onClick="detailsSubmit()">
```

Comment: You want `.value`, not `.toString()`, like for any inputs.

Comment: That `submit` input should be inside your `form`. And you fail to specify what problem you're encountering..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var phNoString = phNo.toString();
```

This line will return `[object HTMLInputElement]`, you need to use `phNo.value` if you want the value the user typed inside the input.

Not really related to the problem, but `<input type="number" name="phNo" max="7">` here the `max` attribute only means the highest number possible in that input is 7. Using a browser that supports html5 inputs it's giving me an invalid highlight if I try to enter any phone number.
I would change it to a simple text field and use the maxlength attribute, which is probably what you intended;

```
<input type="text" name="phNo" maxlength="7">
```

Comment: Wow, looks like that maxlength fixed it without JS needed, as you can only input a length of 7. Weird, I did test the maxlength tag (A lot). I thought it was an HTML5 thing, because it was not working for me. Is now though!

Comment: Number input is new to html5 and surprisingly doesn't support maxlength, that's probably why you couldn't get it to work.
Anyway, I don't suggest relying only on maxlength for validation, it's like using placeholders or input masks, they're helpful but users might still find a way around.

Answer (score 0):

"getElementsByName" returns a collection type, you should be doing like this to read the value from the element.

```
var phNoString  = document.getElementsByName('phNo')[0].value;
if(phNoString.toString().length != 7) {
   //Do something for false 
   return;
} else {
  //Do something for true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did decide to leave it as a number input, you don't need to convert it to a string. Phone Numbers can't start with 0, so the smallest number would be 1000000. If your input has a max of 7, then you can check that the value is greater than that.

```
var phNoString  = document.getElementsByName('phNo')[0].value;
if(var phNoString > 1000000){
// truthy
}else{
// falsey
}
```

Comment: Clever! Did not think of it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The document.getElementsByName() function is depreciated in HTML5. See note in [w3school site](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp). Use `document.getElementById()` instead and add an ID tag to your phone input control.

Also use `input type="tel"` for your phone numbers.  That way the browsers, especially on mobile devices, know how to correctly display the inputted value on the screen.

Finally, note the use of regular expressions to do a validation check on the inputted phone number.  Also, **it is important to note**, the HTML5 regex validation runs after the JavaScript function executes.  Below is a code snippet that you can sink your new developer teeth into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Phone Number (format: xxx-xxx-xxxx):: <input type="tel" id="phNo" name="phNo" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$"/><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="checkphonelength()">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkphonelength(){
            var phNoStringLength = document.getElementById('phNo').value.length;
            if(phNoStringLength === 12) {
              alert("true");
              return true;
            }
            alert(false);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```